# How to place two submit button in a view page with different action in a controller using codeigniter version 3

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have *home_c* controller, *home_m* model and *home_v* view page in code igniter application folder. My view *home_v* page contains following code.

```
<?php
echo form_open('home_c/save');?>
Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Save">
<?php echo form_close();?>
 <?php
echo form_open('home_c/view');?>
<input type="submit" name="view" value="View">
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

My problem is that, I could not execute function *view()* in controller *home_c*. But I can execute same function by placing  instead of the view button. I don't know what is the real issue behind this. Anybody please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please update your controller code also to clear what problem exactly is... Thank you

Comment: do you want to handle multiple submits in home_c controller ?

Comment: @ RanjanaLK :yes,i want to handle more than one submit button

Comment: also share ur controller code

Comment: @Aswathy please post your controller code so, we can see how you handle your submits and see where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

If you want different action for each button, use the a href = base_url 'Controller/Method'.. Like this one, button type = "button" a href=" base_url() . 'Controller/Method'

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->input->post('sub')=='Save'){
$this->your_model->add($data);
 }
 if($this->input->post('view')=='View'){
   $this->load->view('view',$data);
 }
```

Change like this and check

Comment: thank u all....my controller page is working only with one submit button...but when I put second button on my view page,then execution not reached on controller.